# Create DataTable in Shiny

Tags: r, datatable, shiny

I have a dataframe (df). I want users to enter a phrase in Shiny. The Shiny app then takes the last two words of the phrase and filters df according to the trigrams there. The output (a DataTable) should be displayed in the user interface.

However, the server function does not find `lastTwo()` (and maybe also not `lastOne()`). Can anyone tell me why?

Futhermore, how can I extract the column `x3` in `df1` and print it in the UI?

```
require(dplyr)          # data wrangling
require(stringi)        # string/text processing
require(stringr)        # extracting words
require(shiny)
df <- structure(list(term = c("one of the", "a lot of", "thanks for the", 
                              "to be a", "going to be", "i want to", "out of the", "the end of", 
                              "it was a", "as well as", "some of the", "be able to", "part of the", 
                              "i have a", "i have to", "the rest of", "looking forward to", 
                              "is going to", "thank you for", "this is a"), freq = c(3418, 
                                                                                     2969, 2322, 1851, 1749, 1518, 1514, 1466, 1431, 1376, 1372, 1313, 
                                                                                     1230, 1213, 1093, 1084, 1078, 1054, 1030, 1013), share = c(0.000925656110901077, 
                                                                                                                                                0.000804058804349121, 0.000628839522970246, 0.000501284219215299, 
                                                                                                                                                0.000473660777637795, 0.000411101807006388, 0.000410018534787662, 
                                                                                                                                                0.000397019268162954, 0.000387540636249105, 0.000372645643241627, 
                                                                                                                                                0.000371562371022901, 0.000355584105796698, 0.000333106207258141, 
                                                                                                                                                0.000328502300328556, 0.000296004133766787, 0.000293566771274654, 
                                                                                                                                                0.000291941862946565, 0.000285442229634211, 0.000278942596321858, 
                                                                                                                                                0.000274338689392273), x1 = c("one", "a", "thanks", "to", "going", 
                                                                                                                                                                              "i", "out", "the", "it", "as", "some", "be", "part", "i", "i", 
                                                                                                                                                                              "the", "looking", "is", "thank", "this"), x2 = c("of", "lot", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                               "for", "be", "to", "want", "of", "end", "was", "well", "of", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                               "able", "of", "have", "have", "rest", "forward", "going", "you", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                               "is"), x3 = c("the", "of", "the", "a", "be", "to", "the", "of", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             "a", "as", "the", "to", "the", "a", "to", "of", "to", "to", "for", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             "a")), .Names = c("term", "freq", "share", "x1", "x2", "x3"), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         20L), class = "data.frame")




server <- function(input, output) {
        tokens <- reactive({
                token <- tolower(input$sentence)
                token <- gsub("[^[:alnum:]['-]", " ", token)
                token <- gsub("^\\s+|\\s+$", "", token)
        })

        output$lastOne <- renderPrint({
                word(tokens(), -1)
        })

        output$lastTwo <- renderPrint({
                word(tokens(), -2)
        })

        output$table <- renderDataTable({
                df1 <- df %>%
                        filter(x1 == lastTwo() & x2 == lastOn())
                return(df1)

        })
}

ui <- navbarPage("Filter",
                 tabPanel("The App",
                          column(8, offset = 4,
                                 textInput(inputId = "sentence", label = "Enter your phrase"),
                                 submitButton("Filter")
                          ),

                          fluidRow(
                                  dataTableOutput('table')
                          )
                 ),

                 tabPanel("How to use")
)


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, `lastOne` and `lastTwo` should be reactive such as `tokens`. But then it still does not run on my computer since in your code you do not specify the package containing the `word` command.

Comment: now it works, thank you! I have added the required packages! But what about question two? How can I tell shiny to extract a single cell from my table? for example the word in row 10, column "x3"

Comment: Use something like `df$x3[10]` in a `renderPrint` function.

Comment: But where should I put this render function? Furthermore, how can I tell Shiny NOT to display the table, unless the user has something entered?

Comment: In your code above the `renderDataTable` function in `server` is the function which determines the output of the `dataTableOutput` function in `ui`. So, correspondingly, you need a `textOutput` in `ui` whose output is determined by a `renderText` (`renderPrint` in my comment above should have been `renderText`) in `server`. Regarding your second question, have a look at the help pages for `conditionalPanel` or `uiOutput` and `renderUI`.

Comment: when I add  output$text <- renderText({
                df1$x3[1]
        }) after the renderDataTable function, I get "object df1 not found"

Comment: You define the data.frame `df1` in the `output$table` function. This means that it exists only inside this function. So you have to repeat the command `df1 <- df %>% filter( ...` before `df1$x3[1]` in the `renderText`.

Comment: But that slows down everything. Especially when the dataset gets bigger and when I want to get not only the element in row 1 and column x3, but also other elements. Isn't there a way to do all in one process?

Comment: maybe I solved it. i just added output$text <<-  renderText({df1[1,6]}) within the renderDataTable function.

Comment: The best way would be to pack the `df1` into a reactive function like `df1 <- reactive({return(df %>% filter((x1 == lastTwo() & x2 == lastOne())})` and place  `output$text <- renderText({df1()[1,6]})` (note the additional parentheses) outside the `renderDataTable`. You can then modifiy the `renderDataTable` to `output$table<-renderDataTable({return(df1())})` (note again the additional parentheses).

Comment: great, thank you so much! I still have to figure out how to use the conditonalPanel or the uiOutput and renderUI, but you really saved my day!